# Which approach is better and optimized between two of the following?

Tags: java

Below are the two approaches for reversing the string with calling API methods. Please tell which approach is better with due justification

```
public String functionOne(String str){
    char arr[] = str.toCharArray();
    int limit = arr.length/2;
    for (int i = arr.length-1, j = 0; j < limit; i--, j++) {
        char c = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = c;
    }
    return new String(arr);
}

public String functionTwo(String str) {
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    char[] strChars = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i = strChars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        strBuilder.append(strChars[i]);
    }

    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Actually when I run my code on string of length 100000, approach second took double time as that of first approach. By using System.currentTimeMillis() I found execution difference of 1 in first approach and 2 in second approach.

Comment: I am not quite sure with this, but I think the first approach is better

Comment: Better = faster? More readable?

Comment: You are inconsistent in your notation: `char arr[]` vs. `char[] strChars`. The former is supported mainly to alleviate the transition from C++ while the latter is much more readable IMO.

Comment: Improvement to #2: always preallocate memory when using `stringBuilder` or `arrayList` etc: `new StringBuilder(str.length())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
new StringBuilder("some string").reverse().toString();
```

The API already in place for this will likely use the most efficient manner.

Answer (score 1):

Both are equally same. First is using `n/2` operation which is `O(n)` and the second one is doing it in `n` operation which is also of O(n) time complexity.

In practice both will run almost equally well because `n` or `n/2` operation won't make much difference.

EDIT: If you don't get the time complexity meaning, try generating a random string of large length say 1 million and calculate the time for both approach.

Comment: “For every polynomial-time algorithm you have, there is an exponential algorithm that I would rather run.” -- Alan Perlis

Answer (score 1):

Second is more readable: I can skim through that without having to think about what it's doing. I would go with that every time (unless there's a good reason why you need it to be milliseconds quicker?)

The first one stops my brain for a few seconds. That means it's dangerous and can easily be broken by future changes. It either needs comments, or replacing (with the second one).